# How can I find matching data in another worksheet and get a cell value?

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel workbook with 2 worksheets. Let's call them "Item List" and "Item Master".

In "Item List" I have 2 columns, B ("Code") and C ("Subcode"). It looks like this:

```
 A    B    C
----------------
100   AR
110   AR
120   NU
130   AR
```

In "Item Master" I have similar columns, K ("Code") and L ("Subcode"). It looks like this:

```
 E     K    L    
----------------
xx   100   AR
xx   100   AR
xy   120   NU
xc   120   AR
xz   130   AR
```

In "Item List", I need to have column C show the value of "Item Master" column E, IF the values of B and C match the values of K and L.

So if (Item List)A AND (Item List)B match (Item Master)K AND (Item Master)L, then (Item List)C = (Item Master)E

If there are multiple matches, the search can stop after the first match and get the value of column E since it will be the same for all matches.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the `Item Master` sheet, create the following formula in Column M `=(K2&L2)`, then drag it down the rowset.

In column C of the `Item List` sheet write this formula.

```
=Offset(`Item Master`!$E$1,match($A2&$B2,'Item Master`!$M:$M,0)-1,0)
```

then fill down the row set.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use This array formula. You have to use <kbd>CTL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> after you enter the formula. This will negate the use of using a helper column

`=INDEX('Item Master'!E:E,MATCH(1,('Item Master'!L:L=B1)*('Item Master'!K:K=A1),0))`

The above formula goes in `C1` of  `Item List` You can then copy it down...

**SCREENSHOT**
[image]

Comment: Sid, he heeds to look up A&B as a match against K&L, so this won't work as written.

Comment: Yup. I had misread that. Updated the post for any future visitors :)

Comment: @jeffbrady: Did you press CTL+SHIFT+ENTER? I tested it and it works

Comment: AH I see .. I pasted it right into C1. Now, I clicked C1 and pasted it into the formula bar, and then did CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: @JeffBrady: Ah you got it working :) I was uploading a screenshot :)